# JTable erroneous column summation values

Tags: java, swing, jtable, documentlistener

**Scenario** :
 A JTable contains the following data, I have tried to describe what I am trying to do in the image below :-
[image]

*So, I guess I am able to explain what I am trying to achieve here.*

**Problem faced**
Does not display the accurate results (summation), ofcourse. The code I have used is :

```
public void docTotal_Income(){
   try{

       int totC=8,xC=3,lC=4,eC=5, sC=6; // totC is the last column, xC-3rd, lC-4th and so on...


       for(int i=0;i<(easypath.doctorBusiness_table.getRowCount());i++){ // "easypath.doctorBusiness_table" is the table name
           sumTot += Double.parseDouble(easypath.doctorBusiness_table.getModel().getValueAt(i, totC).toString());
           sumTotx += Double.parseDouble(easypath.doctorBusiness_table.getModel().getValueAt(i, xC).toString());
           sumTotl += Double.parseDouble(easypath.doctorBusiness_table.getModel().getValueAt(i, lC).toString());
           sumTote += Double.parseDouble(easypath.doctorBusiness_table.getModel().getValueAt(i, eC).toString());
           sumTots += Double.parseDouble(easypath.doctorBusiness_table.getModel().getValueAt(i, sC).toString());
       }
       easypath.totalEarnt_docBus_tf.setText(String.valueOf(sumTot));
       easypath.xTotIncome_tf.setText(String.valueOf(sumTotx));
       easypath.lTotIncome_tf.setText(String.valueOf(sumTotl));
       easypath.eTotIncome_tf.setText(String.valueOf(sumTote));
       easypath.sTotIncome_tf.setText(String.valueOf(sumTots));

       sumTot = 0;   // public static    
       sumTotx = 0;  // values globally
       sumTotl = 0;  // declared
       sumTote = 0;  // and
       sumTots = 0;  // initialised 0 

       }
       catch(Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in totalling income");
       }
   }
```

I am calling the method **`docTotal_Income()`** after refining the `JTable` with the **`Document Listener`** (*works fine*) and finally firing an `eventListener` on the `JButton`.

```
private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    new doctor().docTotal_Income(); // doctor is the class
}
```

***After all these I get irregular summations. I am guessing I have gone wrong somewhere with logic, but is there any other thing I am missing?***

I would gladly appreciate any suggestion on this. Thanks for your time

Comment: What is an "irregular summation"?  Is your total off by 0.01?  Off by 1,000,000?  Is the total [NaN](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN)?  Infinity?

Comment: Irregular does not mean any error in size or what so ever. I tried to explain that it gives wrong summation , 5+5 = 20 and so on.... which I guess is a **logical error** of mine, but I cant point it out, so has put the whole scenario in this order

Comment: put number to XxxTableModel, override getColumnClass inside models definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new doctor().docTotal_Income(); // doctor is the class
```

First of all class names should start with an upper case character. "doctor()" should be "Doctor()".

Why are you creating a new Doctor()?

If you are trying to filter the data in the TableModel then you need to get the data from the table, not the TableModel.

So your code should be something like:

```
JTable table = easypath.doctorBusiness_table;

for(int i=0; I < table.getRowCount(); i++)
{
       sumTot += Double.parseDouble(table.getValueAt(i, totC).toString());
       sumTotx += Double.parseDouble(table.getValueAt(i, xC).toString());
       sumTotl += Double.parseDouble(table.getValueAt(i, lC).toString());
       sumTote += Double.parseDouble(table.getValueAt(i, eC).toString());
       sumTots += Double.parseDouble(table.getValueAt(i, sC).toString());
}
```

Comment: That worked like charm, there was the mistake `getModel()`, thanks for that, an the other things you mentioned, will definitely keep in mind in the long run. *Learning is so easy for beginners  with SO and people like you @camickr*

Comment: And one more thing, i am creating the `new doctor()....` because this is a different class `easypath` where I am calling, am I doing the right thing or should I change something?

Comment: I don't understand your design or understand what you are attempting to do. But yes, I suspect there is no reason to create a new class when you click on a button. If you are filtering the results of your table then you let the table filter the rows, there is no need to create a new TableModel. Read the Swing tutorial on "How to Use Tables" for a filtering example.

Comment: `docTotal_income()` is in a different class, as there are number of modules, i created different classes for different purposes. So for invoking the method i created an instance for `docTotal_income()`. I know that I am not a pro yet, But can you guide to **the best practices and norms to develop a multi-threaded or heavy applications** like this? I would very much appreciate this.

Comment: Yes, you should design with logical classes. I don't understand how  `docTotal_income()` works. First of all it doesn't follow Java naming conventions. Descriptive words should be upper cased, except for the first. So the method should be `docTotalIncome()`. More importantly you need a reference to the `JTable` and to the `5 JTextFileds` to display the totals. I don't understand how invoking new Doctor() does this. If you need access to those 6 variables, then the code should be defined in the class where you define the components and add them to the GUI.